Android: How to inflate XML view
I'm attempting to add a DatePicker to my android app following the documentation provided by Google here. I'm trying to make it so the picker appears when a button is pushed, allowing the user to input a calendar date. When I try to go to load this button in the app though, it crashes giving me a NullPointerException in logcat. I believe I need to inflate the XML view, but I'm unsure how to go about doing this.
Here is my AssignmentEntryScreen.kt file where I'm attempting to create the button (I've indicated where the relevant code for button is with a comment reading //HERE):
object AssignmentEntryDestination : NavigationDestination, ComponentActivity()  {
    override val route = "assignment_entry"
    override val titleRes = R.string.assignment_entry_title
}

//Manages layout of the assignment entry screen
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AssignmentEntryScreen(
    navigateBack: () -> Unit,
    onNavigateUp: () -> Unit,
    canNavigateBack: Boolean = true,
    viewModel: AssignmentEntryViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    //Title text
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            InventoryTopAppBar(
                title = stringResource(AssignmentEntryDestination.titleRes),
                canNavigateBack = canNavigateBack,
                navigateUp = onNavigateUp
            )
        }
        //Body with data entry field and save button
    ) { innerPadding ->
        AssignmentEntryBody(
            assignmentUiState = viewModel.assignmentUiState,
            onAssignmentValueChange = viewModel::updateUiState,
            //Save button
            onSaveClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    viewModel.saveAssignment()
                    navigateBack()
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(
                    start = innerPadding.calculateStartPadding(LocalLayoutDirection.current),
                    top = innerPadding.calculateTopPadding(),
                    end = innerPadding.calculateEndPadding(LocalLayoutDirection.current),
                )
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
}

//Body function to create field entry boxes and save button
@Composable
fun AssignmentEntryBody(
    assignmentUiState: AssignmentUiState,
    onAssignmentValueChange: (AssignmentDetails) -> Unit,
    onSaveClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_medium)),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_large))
    ) {
        //Name and due date inputs
        AssignmentInputForm(
            assignmentDetails = assignmentUiState.assignmentDetails,
            onValueChange = onAssignmentValueChange,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        //Save button
        Button(
            onClick = onSaveClick,
            enabled = assignmentUiState.isEntryValid,
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(text = stringResource(R.string.save_action))
        }
    }
}

//Name and due date input forums
@Composable
fun AssignmentInputForm(
    assignmentDetails: AssignmentDetails,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onValueChange: (AssignmentDetails) -> Unit = {},
    enabled: Boolean = true
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_medium))
    ) {
        //Name forum
        Text(text = "Assignment")
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = assignmentDetails.name,
            onValueChange = { onValueChange(assignmentDetails.copy(name = it)) },
            label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.assignment_name_req)) },
            colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                focusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
                unfocusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
                disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            enabled = enabled,
            singleLine = true
        )

//HERE  //Date Picker button.
        setContentView(R.layout.datepicker)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.pickDate).setOnClickListener {
            val newFragment = DatePickerFragment()
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"datePicker")
        }

    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
private fun AssignmentEntryScreenPreview() {
    InventoryTheme {
        AssignmentEntryBody(assignmentUiState = AssignmentUiState(
            AssignmentDetails(
                name = "Assignment name", dueDate = Date(5/3/2024)
            )
        ), onAssignmentValueChange = {}, onSaveClick = {})
    }
}


The datePickerFragment.kt itself:
package com.example.assignmentNotifier


import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.app.DialogFragment
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.DatePicker
import com.example.assignmentNotifier.ui.assignment.AssignmentEntryDestination.setContentView
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Locale

@Suppress("DEPRECATION", "OVERRIDE_DEPRECATION")
class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    private val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd, yyyy", Locale.US)

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Dialog {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker.
        setContentView(R.layout.datepicker)

        val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it.
        return DatePickerDialog(activity, this, year, month, day)

    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        calendar.set(year, month, day)
        returnFormattedDate(calendar.timeInMillis)
    }

    private fun returnFormattedDate(timestamp: Long): String? {
        return formatter.format(timestamp)

    }
}

And the R.layout.datepicker.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pick date"/>
    

</LinearLayout>

My understanding is that this that I need to first inflate datepicker.xml before calling findViewById<Button>(R.id.pickDate), but I'm unsure how to go about doing this, or even where I should be placing that code. Other resources I find online use the fragment or Activity file they are working in as context to inflate, but because I'm not in either of those this isn't working for me.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You don't mix compose and view based UI hierarchies like that.  You can set a composable OR set a root view, you can't do both.  So if you use compose, you'd never set a root view via setContentView.
If you want to embed a view inside a compose hierarchy, you need to follow the steps here:  https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose   Basically you wrap it in an AndroidView object in your composition.  If you need to inflate the xml, you wouldn't do it via setContentView.  You use LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate()

Thank you for this. I ended up using an implementation that used compose instead of the view-base UI and it's working properly now.
